# session_regenerate_id before PHP 5.1

Tags: php, authentication, security

I've been looking at using session_regenerate_id in a login class which I have been developing and from reading the PHP documentation and a few other sites it seems that it creates a new session with a newly generated ID carrying across the previous data since the function was added in PHP 4.3.2.

Since PHP 5.1 it has a delete_old_session parameter and if set to true it will also destroy the previous session but in previous versions it will not.

My question is if I was to use session_regenerate_id on a server running a PHP version below 5.1 what would be the best way to use session_regenerate_id and to destroy the previous session?

I don't think session_destroy() would work because if I used it before session_regenerate_id then it wouldn't be able to carry across the previous session data and if used after it would just destroy the new session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
session_start();
// gets current (previous) session
$previousID = session_id();
session_regenerate_id();
// get the new session id
$newID = session_id();
// close session related files
session_write_close();

// set the old session id
session_id($previousID);
// start the old session
session_start();
// clear the old session
session_destroy();
// save the old session state (destroyed session)
session_write_close();

// set the regenerated session id
session_id($newID);
// start the new session
session_start();
```

Now your old session data is erased and transfered to a new session id.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, quite glad in all newer versions of PHP it won't be so long winded to generate a new session ID and destroy the previous one.

Thanks again.